# SharePoint Online - Custom InfoPath forms and changing content types

Tags: infopath, content-type

I have created a SharePoint CRM tool that uses 3 content types - these are named General, Prospect and Account.  The idea being that a new potential customer lead gets added to the database as a General record, then if it progresses to become a potential customer, we change the content type to Prospect.  If it then becomes a customer, we change it to Account.
This works when I use the default forms created by SharePoint - if I open a record, I see a Content Type drop down box at the top of the record where I can then change the record type (content type) between General, Prospect and Account as required - see highlighted bit in image below:
[image: Working]

If I then customise the form in InfoPath, I do not get the Content Type drop down appear either within InfoPath, or the finished form.  Here is what I have customised in InfoPath and on the right, there is no option to select Content Type as a field to add to the form:
[image: InfoPath Form]

And here is the end result once published to SharePoint:
[image: Not Working]

Is there any way I can include the changing of Content Type within my custom forms?

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

please make sure this column is selected in the content type - column order
please make sure this column is selected in the right view
make sure you select the right form to edit from page design
if it is a choice column, please make sure, you put the choices there
or you can also bind data source from any source , by just clicking the control and then control source.. these options you can check. but it seems , the first one might work,

Comment: Sorry, please make sure which column is selected in what content type?  Not really sure where / what I am supposed to be looking at here?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath is not the best of tools to customise forms.  Rather use a client side javascript to improve the look and feel. Just add a "content editor" webpart and reference the link to the script.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to create a list that contains all the columns from your three content types.  The list would use one InfoPath list form that utilizes sections and formatting rules to hide and display fields determined by the value of a new choice field titled **Customer Type** with the options of General, Prospect, Account.

Steps:  1) Create a list, 2) add all the columns from all three content types, 3) create a list form, 4) organize your fields into sections based on customer type, 5) set rules to hide/show sections based on the selected value of the **Customer Type** field.